# Como recuperar o id inserido no banco sqlserver utilizando delphi datasnap

Tags: sql-server, delphi, datasnap, firedac

Como pegar o id que acabou de ser inserido no banco no lado server,
uso Delphi XE10.1 Banco SQlServer e Firedac, gostaria de pegar o id para usar na tabela filho quando for master detalhe. conforme exemplo abaixo

```
procedure TsrmCadastro.dspPessoaBeforeUpdateRecord(Sender: TObject;
    SourceDS: TDataSet; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet; UpdateKind: TUpdateKind;var Applied: Boolean);

var idPessoa : Integer;

begin
if UpdateKind = ukInsert then
begin
  if SourceDS = qryPessoa then
  Begin
    idPessoa              := ????????;
  End
  Else if SourceDS = qryPessoaJuridica then
  Begin
    DeltaDS.FieldByName('pessoa_juridica_id').NewValue := idPessoa;
  End;
end;
```

Comment: Você pode usar [`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ms190315.aspx) no SQL Server 2008+

Comment: Usei como seque exemplo abaixo mas retorna Zero este codigo coloquei no lugar dos ???????

        qry := TFDQuery.Create(self);
        qry.Connection := dm.Conn;
        try
          qry.SQL.Add('SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID');
          qry.Open();
          idPessoa    := qry.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;

        finally
          FreeAndNil(qry);
        end;

Comment: Você tem que executar o SCOPE_IDENTITY() imediatamente depois do INSERT. `INSERT INTO dbo.tabela(nome) VALUES('Nome Sobrenome'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();`